# Force display name as fullname on registration in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find a solution to change the users' display name to their fullname instead of username on registration.

Also I'm using Digits Plugin (User can login and register by phone number).

I set up Digits to set the phone number as the username, but there is no setting for the display name, so when the user registers, the username and display name are the same.

**Is there a way to change display name to first name + last name on user registration and save it in database?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.